# Bind rgb color value with angular 2 style binding

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want to bind a rgb value like "200,55,100" coming from backend to the to the background color of a div.

That does not work, it throws template parse exception.

```
<div [style.background-color]="rgb({{model.color}})"
```

How do I do that correctly?

**UPDATE**

```
<div [style.background-color]="s.getColor()"> class="md-chip" *ngFor="let s of sums">
    <div class="md-chip-img">
        <span style="text-align:center" class="md-chip-span">X</span>
    </div>
    <span class="md-chip-text">{{s.subjectName}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the "s.getColor()" implementation?

Comment: can`t its not anymore in my code :P

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use property binding (the [] syntax) and interpolation (the {{}} syntax) together. The reason for this is that Angular2 creates a property binding behind the scenes for the interpolation (see also [Angular2 docs on interpolation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding)).

I would suggest to try the following with interpolation:

```
<div style.background-color="rgb({{model.color}})">...</div>
```

Or if you want to use the property binding, the following should work:

```
<div [style.background-color]="'rgb(' + model.color + ')'">...</div>
```

Where `getColorString()` is a method that returns the computed string for your rgb value:

```
public getColorString(): string {
  return 'rgb(200, 55, 100)';
}
```

Comment: Should there not be a ":" before the rgb(...) with interpolation? Anyway both ways don`t work. Then I tried also => <div [style.background-color]="{{s.getColor()}}">  I need the s. because thats my ngFor item. Does also not work as s is undefined.

Comment: I mean that does not work: [style.background-color]="s.getColor()"> s is undefined. I have updated my question with my HTML.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest `<div style="background-color=rgb({{model.color}})">...</div>`. Rather use `<div style.background-color="rgb({{model.color}})">...</div>` or `<div [style.background-color]="'rgb(' + model.color + ')'">...</div>`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks, I tried the => [style.background-color]="'rgb(' + model.color + ')'" and it worked!

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I don't mind updating, but could you explain why you wouldn't use `style="background-color=..."`?

Comment: Directly binding to attributes like `class` and `style` doesn't work properly on Safari (mobile). `ngStyle`, `ngClass` or `[style.stylePropName]=...` should be used instead.

Comment: is ngSTyle/ngClass not angularJS 1.x ??? No its not... https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-2-ngclass-and-ngstyle and I read lately that with ng 2 we do not need anymore all those directives, haha.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case of needing client color conversion bound like an attribute directive.

In my case, I used to require this functionality and before Angular, I relied on jQuery to convert the color I set in keywords to RGB for auto-contrasting text on a background. If you need to do the color conversion, check out *color-convert* on npm.

If you tweak the color conversion in `colorBackground()` and `colorText()` you should be able to do the same.

[If you want to see how its used and works, you can check out this stackblitz I was sketching in.](https://murphy-automotive-material-vehicle-tables-poc.stackblitz.io)

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

var convert = require('color-convert');

@Directive({
  selector: '[maAutoContrast]'
})
export class AutoContrastDirective {
  @Input('bgColor')
  // E.g. 'blue'
  public bgColor: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.colorBackground();
    this.colorText();
  }

  private colorBackground(): void {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = this.bgColor;
  }

  private colorText(): void {
    const [r, g, b] = convert.keyword.rgb(this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor);

    // http://www.w3.org/TR/AERT#color-contrast
    const perceivedBrightness = Math.round(((parseInt(r) * 299) +
        (parseInt(g) * 587) +
        (parseInt(b) * 114)) / 1000);

    const foregroundColor = (perceivedBrightness > 125) ? 'black' : 'white';

    this.el.nativeElement.style.color = foregroundColor;
  }
}
```